# Get specific row from dataset using fetch_assoc?

Tags: php, mysql, loops, while-loop, dataset

If I am using the below query and lets say that it returns the below dataset

```
SELECT p.`id`, 
    s.`name`, 
    d.`deployStatus`,
    d.`deployedDate`
FROM `patches` AS p
LEFT JOIN `deployed` AS d ON d.`PatchID` = p.`id`
LEFT JOIN `servers` AS s ON s.`id` = d.`serverID`
WHERE p.`id` = 2
```

---

```
| id | name | deployStatus | deployedDate |
|____|______|______________|______________|
| 2  | test |      1       |  06/14/2013  |
| 2  | prod |     null     |  06/14/2013  |
```

Is there a way with the `while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()){` command that I can return only the "test" row, without having the change the sql query?

Comment: Not without looping through it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use if condition and check whether it is your desired row or not.

```
while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()){
     if($row['name'] == "test") {
         // echo here your result
     }
}
```